# TextInput Maintains focus even after hitting enter on Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I am currently making a simple app in React-Native to keep track of a dollar amount, however once I enter an amount into the input it gets stuck inside the input. The input never loses focus once I hit the enter/return key on the Android keyboard, it even goes inside the addAmount function and prints the warn but still maintains the cursor focus inside the input, this prevents me from pressing r,r again to refresh the app.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, ScrollView} from 'react-native';

class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  addAmount(deposit){
    console.warn(deposit);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue', justifyContent:'center'}}>
          <Text>YTD Earnings: $10</Text>          
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#95a5a6'}}>
          <TextInput
          ref = 'amount'
          placeholder='Enter Amount'
          keyboardType='numeric'
          returnKeyType='done'
          onSubmitEditing={(event) => this.addAmount(event.nativeEvent.text)}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Comment: It would be very kind of you to share the solution you found.